# How to create a multi_line plot with HoverTool using Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

From a Pandas dataframe like the one below, I'm simply trying to create a multi_line plot plus HoverTool; however, I can't find any examples similar to my specific case.  Here is my sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Dataframe (just toy data, this will be an import of a much larger dataset)
index = ['2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-30', '2018-05-31', 
         '2018-06-30', '2018-07-31', '2018-08-31', '2018-09-30', '2018-10-31']

columns = ['Argentina', 'Turkey', 'Mexico']

np.random.seed(123)
data = np.random.rand(10, 3)

df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns, data=data)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.index.name = 'Date'

# Attempt at plot (obviously doesn't work)
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
output_notebook()

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure(plot_height=400)
p.multi_line(xs='Date', ys=columns, source=source)

p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[('Country', '@???'),
                                ('Date', '@Date'),
                                ('Value', '@???')]))

show(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Multi lines](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/multi_line.html) xs and ys should be a list of lists, that's why it didn't work.
I replaced the multiline for 3 normal lines and it should work fine now.
If you really want to use multi line, you should format your data like this:

```
index = ['2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-30', '2018-05-31', 
         '2018-06-30', '2018-07-31', '2018-08-31', '2018-09-30', '2018-10-31']
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
"xs": [index, index, index],
"ys": np.random.rand(3, 10).tolist()
))
```

Working code with line instead of multiline:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = ['2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-30', '2018-05-31', 
         '2018-06-30', '2018-07-31', '2018-08-31', '2018-09-30', '2018-10-31']

columns = ['Argentina', 'Turkey', 'Mexico']

np.random.seed(123)
data = np.random.rand(10, 3)

df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns, data=data)
df['Date'] = index

output_notebook() 
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure(plot_height=400, x_range=index)
p.line(x='Date', y='Argentina', source=source, color='red', legend='Argentina ', name='Argentina')
p.line(x='Date', y='Turkey', source=source, color='blue', legend='Turkey ', name='Turkey')
p.line(x='Date', y='Mexico', source=source, color='green', legend='Mexico ', name='Mexico')
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 0.90
p.legend.click_policy="hide"
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[('Country', '$name'),
                                ('Date', '@Date'),
                                ('Value', '$y')]))

show(p)
```

Version with multiline:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = ['2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-30', '2018-05-31', 
         '2018-06-30', '2018-07-31', '2018-08-31', '2018-09-30', '2018-10-31']

columns = ['Argentina', 'Turkey', 'Mexico']

np.random.seed(123)
data = np.random.rand(10, 3)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns, data=data)
df_transposed = df.transpose()
source = ColumnDataSource({"xs": [df.index.values.tolist()]*len(list(df.columns.values)), "ys": df_transposed.values.tolist(), "colors": ["red", "green", "blue"], "names": list(df.columns.values)})

output_notebook()
p = figure(plot_height=400, x_range=index)
p.multi_line(xs='xs', ys='ys', color = "colors", name="names", legend="names", source=source)
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 0.90
p.legend.click_policy="hide"
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[('Country', '@names'),
                                ('Date', '$x'),
                                ('Value', '$y')]))

show(p)
```

I only had one problem with the hover tool. It doesn't display the correct date. (Now it shows the x  position, if I replaced this for "xs" it would show the whole date list)

Comment: Thanks Jasper, but that actually doesn't work for me.  It doesn't produce the tooltips.  Also, I prefer to use multi_line.

Comment: Weird, works fine when I run it. Maybe it didn't work because I removed the output_notebook() from the answer because I wasn't running it in a notebook, or maybe we're using a different version of Bokeh? I'm using Bokeh 1.0.1. Anyways, I added the line again and added a version with multiline.

Comment: With bokeh version 2.2.3 the tooltips are not visualizing for the multi_line example. In my chrome console, i'm getting the error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined at b._update (bokeh.min.js?v=c77564ca8be6e4b5a67648d980fe180d62bd99ccfc01bd272a3e708b9533f34b1c86b24a1a28c86555f838fa26e429697aad84c411cac25f0472231ed56f1eab:569) ...' whenever I scroll over a line. 

@Jasper any idea why it wouldn't work?

Comment: There was an issue with adding tooltips to multiline glyphs but it looks like you also discovered that...  I still have this issue with the most recent version (2.2.3) so I'm not sure how to fix this issue.
https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/10458